# Ionic serve throw run time error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic2

I am developing an IONIC2 hybrid app. but when I run ionic serve command its throws after build process.

dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

Error: app-scripts serve unexpectedly failed.

(node:3412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejecti
on (rejection id: 1): Error: channel closed
(node:3412) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections th
at are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

the output of ionic info is given bellow

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.0.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.0.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.0.0
OS         : Linux 4.8
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.
I will appreciate your help and say good luck for the future.

Comment: Restart the app.I read in many blogs where this solution can work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a month since you asked this, but I had the same issue appear suddenly. I removed both the platforms and reloaded them.

```
cordova plugin save
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add iOS
```

I did those commands (you can skip the iOS ones if you aren't doing an iOS app). After that I was able to run the simulator and package the app.